# How i can combine different database table into one using SQL?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Here is my database

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ufQ7cpPPtcrQ17GAhLHP3W/12

Expected output based on from and to date (fromdate = 2007-01-01 todate=2009-10-01 of invoice,receipt,creditnote)

```
  type      date         description  invoiceno debit      credit      balance
    INV       2007-01-24   LPO:RC/1086   1001        100.00             100.00
    INV       2007-03-24   LPO:RC/1098   1002        200.00             300.00
    Receipt   2007-04-04   2002          1001                 50.00     250.00
    Receipt   2007-04-04   2002          1002                 100.00    150.00
    Receipt   2007-11-28   2003          1002                 100.00    50.00
    INV       2008-02-14   LPO:RC/929    1003        500.00             550.00
    Receipt   2008-07-07   2004          1003                 500.00    50.00
    INV       2008-08-16   LPO:RC/815    1004        20.00              70.00
    Receipt   2008-12-23   2005          1004                 20.00     50.00
    INV       2009-01-02   LPO:RC/999    1005        1000.00            1050.00
  CreditNote  2009-01-02   3005          1005                 1000.00   50.00
  
                                                             
Total debit: 820.00
Total credit: 770.00
Total bal: 50.00
```

Controller

```
public function list_soa(){
        $val                         = $this->input->post('id');
        $start_date =$this->input->post('from');
        $end_date =$this->input->post('to');
        $data['all_soa_details']     = $this->createcompany->getSalesWithPayments($val,$start_date,$end_date);
        echo json_encode($data);
        return;
    }
```

Modal:

```
  public function getSales($id)
    {
        $q = $this->db->get_where('invoice_details', array('comp_id' => $id));

        if( $q->num_rows() > 0 ) {
            return $q->result();
        } 
        return FALSE;
    }

    public function getPayments($id)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('receipt_details a');
        $this->db->join('received_amount_details b', 'b.receipt_no =a.rece_No', 'left');
        $this->db->where('a.comp_id', $id);
        
        $query = $this->db->get();
        
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result();
        } 
        return FALSE;
    }
    
    
    public function getSalesWithPayments($companyId,$from,$to) {
    $sales = [];
    foreach ($this->getSales($companyId) as $sale) {
        $sale->payment = null;
        $sales[$sale->invoice_ID] = $sale;
    }
    foreach ($this->getPayments($companyId) as $payment) {
        $sales[$payment->invoice_no]->payment = $payment;
    }
    return $sales;
}
```

AJAX:

```
$('#fileterallsoa').click(function(event) {
     var getID_comp = $('#getID_comp').val();
     var from       =       $('#fromdate_soa_view').val();
     var to        = $('#todate_soa_view').val();
     
     $.ajax({
            url: base_url + "index.php/welcome/list_soa/",
            
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                "id": getID_comp,
                "from": from,
                "to": to
               
            },
            success: function(data) {
                 var new_data = $.parseJSON(data);
                console.log(new_data);
                
            }
     });
});
```

How to show result in one table as i given above? i need to show date wise of invoice,receipt and credit note date and calculate balance amount for the customer?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a select statement that joins the 3 tables.

```
    $this->db->select('a.comp_id,a.date');
    $this->db->from('invoice_details a');
    $this->db->inner_join('receipt_details b','b.receipt_no=a.comp_id', 'left')
    $this->db->inner_join('received_amount_details c', 'b.receipt_no =c.rece_No', 'left')
```

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ufQ7cpPPtcrQ17GAhLHP3W/22

Comment: you know why the balance amount showing -100,-300??